# Conditional pdfs on Standard Normal Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-probability, density-function

Consider $Z \sim N[0,1]$. The standard normal probability density function is given by
\begin{equation}
\phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}
\end{equation}
We define
\begin{equation}
\Phi(x)=\int^z_{-\infty} \phi(x)dx
\end{equation}
which is the probability that $Z<z$.

---

I am asked to compute the probability density of Z conditional on Z>0.

I know this translates to 
\begin{equation}
P(Z=z|Z>0)=\frac{P(Z=z \cap Z>0)}{P(Z>0)}
\end{equation}
I know that I compute the numerator from the given relation for $\Phi(x)$ but I am having trouble with the numerator.
How can I simplify the numerator $P(Z=z \cap Z>0)$?

Comment: Maybe you have to compute $P(Z\leq z|Z>0)$.

Comment: I´ve written in the answer what my comment means to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would firstly compute  $\begin{equation} \text{P(Z<z|Z>0)}\end{equation}$ to obtain the cdf.

$$\begin{equation} \text{P(Z<z|Z>0)}\end{equation}=\frac{P(Z<z\cap Z>0)}{P(Z>0)}=\frac{P(0<Z<z)
}{P(Z>0)}$$

- $P(0<Z<z)=P(Z<z)-P(z<0)=\Phi(z)-\frac12$
- $P(Z>0)=\frac12$

$\Rightarrow \frac{P(0<Z<z)
}{P(Z>0)}= 2\Phi(z)-1$, where $\Phi(z)$ is the cdf of the standard normal distribution.

Let $A$ be the event that $Z>0$. Then the cdf is

$$F_{Z|A}(z)=\begin{cases} 0, \ z<0 \\ 2\cdot \Phi(z)-1, \ 0 \leq z<\infty \end{cases}$$

Now differentiate to obtain the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

$P(Z=z|Z\gt 0)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}$ for $z\gt 0$ and $=0$ otherwise.  Here P is the probability density function, not the distribution function.

Comment: Isn´t $P(Z=z|Z>0)=0$, since $Z$ is continuous?

Comment: @callculus  I forgot to indicate I was describing the density function, not the distribution function. I have since added a note to my answer.  My result agrees with yours.

Comment: OK, but what does $P$ stand for?

Comment: $P(Z=z|Z\gt 0)$ is the probability density function for $Z=z$ under the condition $Z\gt 0$.  $P$ is simply shorthand for the density function being described.